# What are static code blocks for?

Tags: java, static, block, javap

I want to ask what javap shows besides the public fields and methods of the classes passed to it.

I was reviewing a class file having only a static variable. As expected, javap shows the static variable and class constructor as output but it also shows something like:

```
static {};
```

What does this line mean?

Comment: It means static block;

Comment: It is a [static initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

static code block initializes the static variables in the program. it gets executed when the class is initiated, even before constructor call.

Answer (score 4):

- This is a `static` block which is used for initializing values
- This block gets executed when the class is initialized
- The static initializer block is executed whenver the class is initialized and the order of execution is according to their appearance in program.

Comment: *"This block gets executed when the class is loaded into JVM"*. No, it is executed when the class is *initialized*.

Comment: It is executed each time a class is initialized (which might be more than once with multiple class loaders)

Answer (score 0):

javap -private -verbose class will show you the constant pool and the details of the method bytecode.